# how to find the number of vertex that are reachable from a given vertex in Spark GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to find out the number of reachable vertexes from a given vertex in a directed graph (see image below), e.g. for id=0L, since it connects to 1L and 2L, 1L connects to 3L, 2L connects to 4L, hence, the output should be 4. Following is the graph relationship data:

```
edgeid from to distance
0 0 1 10.0
1 0 2 5.0
2 1 2 2.0
3 1 3 1.0
4 2 1 3.0
5 2 3 9.0
6 2 4 2.0
7 3 4 4.0
8 4 0 7.0
9 4 3 5.0
```

I was able to set up the graph, but I am not sure how to use graph.edges.filter to get the ouput

```
val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (Double))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)
val graph: Graph[(Double), Int] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)
```

[image]

Comment: Was my answer something you were looking for? Can you please provide feedback or otherwise accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

In your example all vertices are connected with a directed path so each vertex should result in a value of 4.

But if you were to remove the 4->0 *(id=8)* connection  there would be a different number of course.

Since your problem relies on (recursively) traversing the graph in parallel the [Graphx Pregel API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#pregel-api) is probably the best approach.

The pregel call takes 3 functions

- `vprog` to initialize each vertex with a message (in your case empty `List[VertexId]`)
- `sendMsg` an update step that is applied on each iteration (in your case accumulation the neighboring `VertexId`s and returning an `Iterator` with messages to send out to the next iteration
- `mergeMsg` to merge two messages (2 `List[VertexId]`s into 1)

In code it would look like:

```scala
  def vprog(id: VertexId, orig: List[VertexId], newly: List[VertexId]) : List[VertexId] = newly

  def mergeMsg(a: List[VertexId], b: List[VertexId]) : List[VertexId] = (a ++ b).distinct

  def sendMsg(trip: EdgeTriplet[List[VertexId],Double]) : Iterator[(VertexId, List[VertexId])] = {
    val recursivelyConnectedNeighbors = (trip.dstId :: trip.dstAttr).filterNot(_ == trip.srcId)

    if (trip.srcAttr.intersect(recursivelyConnectedNeighbors).length != recursivelyConnectedNeighbors.length)
      Iterator((trip.srcId, recursivelyConnectedNeighbors))
    else
      Iterator.empty
  }

  val initList = List.empty[VertexId]

  val result = graph
    .mapVertices((_,_) => initList)
    .pregel(
      initialMsg = initList,
      activeDirection = EdgeDirection.Out
    )(vprog, sendMsg, mergeMsg)
    .mapVertices((_, neighbors) => neighbors.length)

  result.vertices.toDF("vertex", "value").show()
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+
|vertex|value|
+------+-----+
|     0|    4|
|     1|    3|
|     2|    3|
|     3|    1|
|     4|    1|
+------+-----+
```

Make sure to experiment with `spark.graphx.pregel.checkpointInterval` if you are getting OoM's traversing large graphs (or configuring the `maxIterations` in pregel init)